# Include quoted original message in mailto link body

Tags: email, gmail, mailto

I'm generating `mailto` links in support emails to make it easier to reply to customers directly from within Gmail. A typical mailto link might look like this:

`mailto:customer@example.com?subject=Re%3A%20Feedback%20%20%20%5B1620394320%5D&body=%0A%0A%3E%20Original%20message%20from%20customer%40example.com%2C%202021-05-07%3A%0A%3E%20Customer%20message%20here`

This works, except the original message is interpreted literally, even though the lines start with `>`  (which I had expected to be interpreted as a quote of a previous message).

So the reply email would literally look like this for the customer:

```
> Original message from customer@example.com, 2021-05-07:
> Customer message here
```

What I want is for the lines starting with `>`  to be treated as a quote of the original message, just like when replying to an email from any email client.

Is it possible to make Gmail do this with a body included in a `mailto` link?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I've been searching for the exact same thing.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Unfortunately not. I eventually just decided to ignore the fact that the lines are treated as normal text. I guess most people won't read past the `Original message from...` line anyway ;) But if you do come up a with a solution, please post it as an answer here!